# Segmentation fault when creating custom autograd function that calls Julia code

Tags: python, pytorch, julia

I have a (vector-to-scalar) function and corresponding derivative function written in Julia that I am unable to translate to Python. I would like to use these within PyTorch by defining a custom autograd function. For simplicity, lets assume this function is `sum()`. This gives the following MRE:

```python
import numpy as np
import torch
from julia import Main

class JuliaSum(torch.autograd.Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        
        x = input.cpu().detach().numpy()

        return torch.FloatTensor([Main.sum(x)]).to('cuda')
        # return torch.FloatTensor([np.sum(x)]).to('cuda')

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        x = input.cpu().detach().numpy()

        y = torch.FloatTensor(Main.ones(len(x))).to('cuda')
        # y = torch.FloatTensor(np.ones(len(x))).to('cuda')

        return grad_output * y

input = torch.FloatTensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).to('cuda').requires_grad_()

# Works — outputs `tensor([0.6000], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<JuliaSumBackward>)`
y = JuliaSum.apply(input)
print(y)

# Works — outputs `tensor([1., 1., 1.], device='cuda:0') `
x = input.cpu().detach().numpy().astype(np.float64)
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(main.ones(len(x))).to('cuda')
print(torch.ones(1).to('cuda') * y_test)

# Doesn't work — segmentation fault
y.backward(torch.ones(1).to('cuda'))
print(input.grad)
```

Calling the forward method works fine, as does running the code contained in the `backward` method from the global scope. However, when I call the `backward` method, I receive:

```
signal (11): Segmentation fault
in expression starting at none:0
Allocations: 3652709 (Pool: 3650429; Big: 2280); GC: 5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The exact line command causing the issue is `Main.ones(len(x))`. Replacing this with `Main.ones(3)` still causes a segmentation fault, so it appears to be an issue with PyJulia accessing memory that has been deallocated.

Also note that when I replace the two calls to Julia with the corresponding NumPy commands (left commented-out), the `backward` method works fine. The code also works when all tensors are on the CPU but my application requires GPU-acceleration.

What is causing this segmentation fault, and how can alter my code to avoid it whilst keeping PyTorch tensors on the GPU?

---

I've included a Dockerfile that matches my environment to make reproducing this issue as simple as possible. For reference, I am using an RTX 3060.

```docker
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu22.04 

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.1
ARG JULIA_VERSION=1.7.1

ENV container docker
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
ENV MAKEFLAGS -j4

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# DEPENDENCIES
#===========================================
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make wget libffi-dev \
        build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
        libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev \
        libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils \
        git

# INSTALL PYTHON
#===========================================
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz && \
    tar -zxf Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz && \
    cd Python-$PYTHON_VERSION && \
    ./configure --with-ensurepip=install --enable-shared && make && make install && \
    ldconfig && \
    ln -sf python3 /usr/local/bin/python
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
    python -m pip install julia numpy torch

# INSTALL JULIA
#====================================
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abelsiqueira/jill/main/jill.sh && \
    bash /app/jill.sh -y -v $JULIA_VERSION && \
    export PYTHON="python" && \
    julia -e 'using Pkg; ENV["PYTHON"] = "/usr/local/bin/python"' && \
    python -c 'import julia; julia.install()'

# CLEAN UP
#===========================================
RUN rm -rf /app/jill.sh \
    /opt/julias/*.tar.gz \
    /app/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz
RUN apt-get purge -y gcc make wget zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev \
        libbz2-dev libreadline-dev \
        libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils && \
    apt-get autoremove -y

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```